# Function with event listeners does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am new to coding, I am trying to figure out why my functions do not appear to be working in my live preview of my simple calculator. Every time I press a button, the page seems to refresh itself and not perform the function.

```
function buttons() {
        var in1 = document.getElementById("input1");
        var in2 = docuemnt.getElementById("input2");
        var res = document.getElementById("result");
        var add = document.getElementById("button1");
        var sub = document.getElementById("button2");
        var mul = document.getElementById("button3");
        var div = document.getElementById("button4");

          add.addEventListener("click,", function () {
                res = in1 + in2;
          });

          sub.addEventListener("click,", function () {
            res = in1 - in2;
          });

          mul.addEventListener("click,", function () {
            res = in1 * in2;
          });

          div.addEventListener("click,", function () {
            res = in1 / in2;
        });
    }
```

I've tried adding an if statement but it doesn't appear to be working

Comment: `docuemnt`  is not the right spelling.

Comment: There is a comma inside the strings `"click,"`.

Comment: Your inputs themselves can't be used to perform math, you want to get the value inside the input, like `res.value = in1.value + in2.value`

Comment: buttons in a form will by default submit the form, which may explain why your page refreshes. That effect needs to be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple syntax errors

```js
function buttons() {
  var in1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  var in2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  var add = document.getElementById("button1");
  var sub = document.getElementById("button2");
  var mul = document.getElementById("button3");
  var div = document.getElementById("button4");

  add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    res.textContent = +in1.value + +in2.value;
  });

  sub.addEventListener("click", function() {
    res.textContent = in1.value - in2.value;
  });

  mul.addEventListener("click", function() {
    res.textContent = in1.value * in2.value;
  });

  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    res.textContent = in1.value / in2.value;
  });
}

buttons()
```

```html
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<p id="result"></p>
<button id="button1">+</button>
<button id="button2">-</button>
<button id="button3">*</button>
<button id="button4">/</button>
```